# How to send messages to an SQS queue in a different AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

My company has multiple accounts and I am writing a lambda in account 1 that needs to write to an SQS queue in account 2. My code looks like this:

```
logger.info(f"{len(entries)} batch entries built")
    sqs_queue = environ["SQS_QUEUE"]
    try:
        logger.info("Getting SQS queue url...")
        queue_url = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=sqs_queue)['QueueUrl']
        # iterate over entries in batches of 10
        for batch in [entries[index:index + sqs_batch_limit] for index in range(0, len(entries), sqs_batch_limit)]:
            logger.info(f"Sending batch of {len(batch)} records to sqs...")
            sqs.send_message_batch(
                QueueUrl=queue_url,
                Entries=batch
            )
```

The problem is that in both accounts, there's an SQS queue named `sqs-queue-data` so the code I wrote above will be default write to the SQS queue in the same account as this lambda. So what can be done?

Comment: Have the Lambda write to SNS and add an inline policy for the SNS topic that allows the other account to subscribe to that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `QueueOwnerAWSAccountId` argument when you're calling `get_queue_url` e.g.

```py
queue_url = sqs.get_queue_url(
  QueueName=sqs_queue,
  QueueOwnerAWSAccountId=1234567890
)['QueueUrl']
```

Docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.get_queue_url

Comment: Nice one! The destination queue would also need permissions configured to allow Account 1 to put a message into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this link and you will be good to go!
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/access-cross-account-resources-using-aws-iot-rules-engine/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be _helpful_, but avoid making it _necessary_ to click on them as much as possible.